# Entity Framework.Refresh context

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, signalr

I’m a beginner in C#. Please help me which direction to go.I have console application which makes changes to my database. I wanna make web service to display information.I've link with DB by EntityFrameworkCore, for online stream data I chose SignalR. My web app display information but when I makes changes I must refresh my page for reload EF database context and load updated datas from DB.

After long internet searching I understand that I must use dinamic context for my situation.But how to realize it in EFCore? I'm confused.Is there a simple solution to this problem or a good resource for learning dinamic context.I will be grateful to you for any help.

my hub

```
public class StreamHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly LContext _context; // conn to Database

        public ChatHub(LContext _context)
        {
            this._context = _context;
        }

        public ChannelReader<string> DelayCounter(int delay) //that method I indicate in js-client

        {
            var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

            _ = WriteItems(channel.Writer, 200, delay);

            return channel.Reader;
        }

        private async Task WriteItems(ChannelWriter<string> writer, int count, int delay)
        {

            for (; ; ) //endless cycle
            {

                string LL = _context.Logs.OrderByDescending(s => s.OccurTime).FirstOrDefault().Flag; //that data which I want to streaming

                await writer.WriteAsync(LL);
                await Task.Delay(delay);
                await _context.Entry(LL).ReloadAsync();
                _context.Entry(LL).Reload();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things. DbContexts are not thread-safe so they should only be scoped within the thread they are accessed. Module-level variables would be a no-no. DbContexts are also pretty cheap to spin up once that first one-off hit for resolving their mapping has been paid. (Very first query against a DbContext of that type) Spin one up when it's needed, especially for multi-threaded or async operations.

```
string LL = _context.Logs.OrderByDescending(s => s.OccurTime).FirstOrDefault().Flag; //that data which I want to streaming
```

This can be more efficient. Your code effectively does:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Logs ORDER BY OccurTime DESC
```

Better would be:

```
string LL = context.Logs
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.OccurTime)
    .Select(s => s.Flag)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This amounts to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Flag FROM Logs ORDER BY OccurTime DESC
```

The difference being the first query returns all properties of the log when we only care about the Flag property.

These lines look fine...

```
await writer.WriteAsync(LL);
await Task.Delay(delay);
```

These don't make any sense. The "flag" is not an entity to reload, and these are the same method, just async vs sync flavours.

```
await _context.Entry(LL).ReloadAsync();
_context.Entry(LL).Reload();
```

I would change the code to look something like this for a start:

```
   private async Task WriteItems(ChannelWriter<string> writer, int count, int delay)
    {

        while (!_abort)
        {
            using(var context = new LContext())
            {
                string flag = _context.Logs
                    .OrderByDescending(s => s.OccurTime)
                    .Select(s => s.Flag)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                await writer.WriteAsync(flag);
            }
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
    }
```

where _abort is a volatile Boolean by which we could have code/user to signal that the background task should terminate gracefully.

Given that this code would be running frequently, I would be considering a solution that writes to the log database but then also keeps a recent in-memory rolling cache of entries for something like this to draw down on as hitting the DB every 200ms adds to load for something that might not be critical in real-time.

Comment: Wow! Big thanks for so helpful and informative answer and code review!